# protobuf-net: Possible recursion detected

Tags: c#, serialization, recursion, protobuf-net

I get an exception trying to serialize object graph (not very deep). Meaningful part of it is like this:

> [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: ProtoBuf.ProtoException: Possible
>   recursion d etected (offset: 5 level(s)): red at
>   ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.CheckRecursionStackAndPush (object) <0x00127> at
>   ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.StartSubItem (object,ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter,bool)
>   <0x0002f>

The graph represents file/directory structure and my model (simplified) looks like this:

```
[ProtoContract] 
[ProtoInclude(100, typeof(PackageDirectory))]
[ProtoInclude(200, typeof(PackageFile))]
public abstract class PackageMember
{
   [ProtoMember(1)] 
   public virtual string Name { get; protected set; }

   [ProtoMember(2, AsReference=true)] 
   public PackageDirectory ParentDirectory { get; protected set; }  
}

[ProtoContract]
public class PackageDirectory : PackageMember
{
   [ProtoMember(3)]
   private Dictionary<string, PackageMember> _children;

   public PackageDirectory()
   {
      _children = new Dictionary<string, PackageMember>();
   }

   public PackageDirectory (string name, PackageDirectory parentDirectory)
      : this()
   {
      this.ParentDirectory = parentDirectory;
      this.Name = name;         
   }

   public void Add (PackageMember member)
   {
      _children.Add(member.Name, member);
   }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class PackageFile : PackageMember
{
   private Stream _file;
   private BinaryReader _reader;

   private PackageFile() 
   {}

   public PackageFile (string name, int offset, int length, PackageDirectory directory,  Stream file)
   {
      this.Name = name;
      this.Length = length;
      this.Offset = offset;
      this.ParentDirectory = directory;

      _file = file;
      _reader = new BinaryReader(_file);
   }

   [OnDeserialized]
   protected virtual void OnDeserialized(SerializationContext context)
   {
      var deserializationContext = context.Context as DeserializationContext;

      if (deserializationContext != null)
      { 
         _file = deserializationContext.FileStream;
         _reader = new BinaryReader(_file);
      }
   }

   [ProtoMember(3)]
   public int Offset { get; private set; }

   [ProtoMember(4)]
   public int Length { get; private set; }
}
```

The depth of this tree is near 10-15 levels, which less than `ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.RecursionCheckDepth` value (25). (So maybe this is a bug?)
The **version of protobuf-net** used is one compiled from trunk **v2** (**rev 491**).

Actually, i solved it with modification of protobuf-net code. I changed value of `ProtoBuf.ProtoWriter.RecursionCheckDepth` to 100 and everything seems to be ok.

The question is if there any "true" way to serialize such kind of graph without modification of protobuf code? Is such a behavior correct or it's a bug?

My platform is **Mono-2.10-8 on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit**

P.S. Also i found that if i deserizlie with thw following code, i should have PackageDirectory parameterless constructor to be public.

```
var value = new PackageDirectory();
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Deserialize(ms, value, typeof(PackageDirectory), new SerializationContext {
   Context = new DeserializationContext {
   FileStream = _file,
}});
```

It's another topic but it's well illustrated with presented code. I think that in this case declaring private constructor should be allowed because now the behavior differs from one for Serializer.Deserialize(...).

Comment: The constructor issue sounds odd and unexpected - again, would need repro; what platform is this running on? regular .NET? or...? (SL and  CF have some subtle differences here, due to platform limitations)

Comment: @MarcGravell, Sorry for incomplete information, i forgot to specify my platform. It's mono. I'll edit a question.

Comment: mono on...? Linux? iOS? Also: which **exact** version number are you using?

Comment: Mark, as i promissed, i did an update of my question right after the comment. You probably missed it. The version is already specified, i repeat it here: Mono-2.10-8 on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit

Comment: And the exact protobuf-net version?

Comment: As i pointed, it's today trunk version, i think it's v2.0 rev 491. I'll put it into question too. Should be more precise

Comment: Because directory is-a-member-of a dictionary is-a-member-of a directory, the recursive depth of actual objects is at least twice the depth of the directory tree you're modelling.

Comment: @BenVoigt, sure you are right, but is the described behavior is still ok? I think, it's reasonable, but it's still unclear, what to do in my case.

Answer (score 6):

This exception is thrown only when the same **reference** is seen in the data (twice in the same path), and tracking is *only enabled* when the depth is at least `RecursionCheckDepth`. Which immediately makes me suspicious of the 10-15 depth limit cited, although it is not necessarily the case that protobuf handles levels *quite* the same as you are counting. It does not make sense to me that raising this number to 100 should make it work - in fact, the very existence of this `RecursionCheckDepth` is purely an optimisation to limit the effort involved in "typical" graphs, only enabling the more rigorous checking if it starts to look deep.

I am, however, mindful that this might also suggest some subtle bug in inheritance-based handling, perhaps also related to `AsReference`. I use protobuf-net extensively and constantly, and I haven't seen such an issue. If you have a reproducible repro I would very much like to see it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Changing RecursionCheckDepth was only a temporary solution to allow me move further with my project, so it's not really an option... I'll prepare reproduceable example of an error tomorrow and will share it somewhere.

Comment: You're actually trying to detect *cycles*, right?  Recursion seems completely normal, although it too could be harmful if deep enough. (linked list anyone?)

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, it is cycles that are the issue here (since this is a tree-based serializer, with limited optional reference-tracking support)

Comment: @Marc: Then the error message and documentation should probably talk about *cycles*, as in "Cycle detected".  And the offset in recursion depth is the *length of the cycle*.

Comment: @Marc: I don't mean to denigrate the excellent work you've done with protobuf.  Please consider this a suggested improvement.

Comment: I have the same problem with Entity Framework Self Tracking entities during serialization. For example, a person as one or more addresses and each address relates to the person. I don't know yet how to tell EF to not reference its parent in a related entity when eager loading the related entities.

Comment: Just solved my circular reference problem. I've added "AsReference = true" to the ProtoMember attribute when the property is a navigation property.

Comment: @MarcGravell Since the "AsReference" property is now obsolete, what would be an alternative for this ?

Comment: @AnuViswan my recommendation is to normalize that protobuf is a tree serializer, and therefore not try to serialize cyclic graphs. Keep in mind that it is fairly normal to have a separate domain model and serialization model, so: even if your domain model is cyclic: the serialization doesn't need to be